# voltmeter circuit using BL0937

Tags: voltage, circuit-design, power-electronics, sensor, metering

I am designing circuit to measure ac voltage only of any source I am using BL0937 and add random load (capacitor 470nf) to Just complete circuit.
the output of pin CF1 is 1.8V but after I add transistor to turn on optocoupler or without transistor when I direct connect CF1 pin to optocoupler the voltage of CF1 pin drop to 0.2v so nothing work can you help me.
the output must be pulsed to measure the voltage using input capture frequency.
[image]